# ASP.NET Identity Multitenant login issue

Tags: asp.net-identity, multi-tenant

I set up multitenancy for my ASP.NET MVC project with standard ASP.Net Identity cookie authentication. So I have the master tenant (regular tenant plus access to some tenant admin tools) accessible on mysite.com, and different tenants on t1.mysite.com, t2.mysite.com.

A login made on t1.mysite.com is not valid on t2.mysite.com, which is just what I want. However, if I login to mysite.com, then while logged in, access tX.mysite.com, it appears as if I'm still logged in. Even though the identity the application things I have doesn't even exist.

Is there any way to ensure that the authentication cookie received for mysite.com is not valid on tX.mysite.com so that admins can't accidentally end up in a non working tenant (the GUI is visible, but you can't do anything since the login for mysite.com is not valid on tx.mysite.com so it's best to just show the login screen)

Answer (score 0):

In your `App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs` file you should have a bit about `OnValidateIdentity`:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<Infrastructure.Identity.UserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => manager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie))
    },
    // Other stuff
});
```

See that parameter `validateInterval` - by default it is set to 30 minutes. This is how often the cookie is actually compared to the values in the database.

Change the value to be `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)`. This will compare the cookie to the value in the database every 30 seconds and if the identity for the tenant is not valid - user will be presented with a login portal.

You can also change it to 0, but I feel that will be overloading your database - on every request there will be a few calls to the DB.

Also there is a property `CookieDomain` property on `CookieauthenticationOptions`:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    // other stuff
    CookieDomain = "example.com"
});
```

This might help you, but because this item is configured so early in the pipeline it might be hard to reconfigure during the runtime.

Another option is to have multiple cookie authenticaion middlewares, but this will only work if your number of tenants is known and very limited:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    // other stuff
    AuthenticationType = "myTenant1",
    CookieDomain = "t1.example.com"
});

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    // other stuff
    AuthenticationType = "myTenant2",
    CookieDomain = "t2.example.com"
});
```

but this might give you more headaches than it actually worth.

Comment: Hmm, I guess that would redirect the user to the proper login page after 30 seconds, which is better than nothing, but still not quite the immediacy I was looking for. Since my data store is "remote", I'd like to keep the number of requests down.

So, isn't there a way to just look at the authorization cookie, compare domains and if it's only a partial match, return unauthorized. I'm dabbling with a custom CookieAuthenticationProvider at the moment but I haven't gotten there yet - and I suspect this may run into the same limitation.

Answer (score 0):

So I've found another way to deal with the problem. It seems I can directly hook into the cookie authentication and just reject the identity if it's from the wrong tenant.

So I wrote my custom CookieAuthenticationProvider

```
public class TenantCookieAuthenticationProvider: CookieAuthenticationProvider
{

    public override Task ValidateIdentity(CookieValidateIdentityContext context)
    {
        string tenantId = SubdomainRoute.GetSubdomain(context.Request.Host.Value);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantId)) // we're trying to access mysite.com from x.mysite.com
        {
            context.RejectIdentity();
            return Task.FromResult<int>(0);
        }
        return base.ValidateIdentity(context);
    }
}
```

and hook it into the authentication pipeline in Startup.cs

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new TenantCookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
```

Of course, that's only half the battle.. the other half is not rejecting the identity in case it's a valid tenant user. As I'm adding the tenantId as a claim when creating the users, I can extract and compare those claims so as not to reject valid tenant users. So I adapted ValidateIdentity as follows

```
public override Task ValidateIdentity(CookieValidateIdentityContext context)
    {
        System.Security.Claims.Claim tenantClaim = context.Identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Subject.Name == "tenant");
        string tenantId = SubdomainRoute.GetSubdomain(context.Request.Host.Value);
        if (tenantClaim != null)
        {
            if (tenantId != tenantClaim.Value)
            {
                context.RejectIdentity();
                return Task.FromResult<int>(0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantId)) // we're trying to access audm.local from x.audm.local
            {
                context.RejectIdentity();
                  return Task.FromResult<int>(0);
            }
        }
        return base.ValidateIdentity(context);
    }
```

And now I even have an additional layer of security so users can't "hop between tenants".